# Configuring IIS7 Caching for Extensionless URLs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, iis

I have an ASP.Net MVC 3 website with several different routes configured. For some of those routes, I would like to have the output cached by IIS. When I look at the [caching configuration for IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691315%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), however, it seems that a file extension is a required attribute.

How do I cache URLs that have no extension? Would .cshtml be the actual extension that is cached?

Here is an example cache configuration copied directly from [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/managing-performance-settings/walkthrough-iis-output-caching):

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <caching>
            <profiles>
                <add extension=".jpg" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" 
                duration="00:00:10" varyByHeaders="Accept-Language" />
            </profiles>
        </caching>                  
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

How would I modify this example to cache the output of these extensionless routes?